# Uploading files from one site to another

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

I have 2 asp.net sites (site1 and site2). site1 have a directory inside in called images. In images directory there are images. I need to upload files using site2 aspx page, but need to upload them to images folder of site1. how can I do that?

Comment: Cant you just write directly to the folder using the real physical path ("C:\Inetpub\Wwwroot\Site1\images")?

Comment: Will try to, maybe it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot write directly to the folder or the sites are on different servers then best option is to upload the file to site 1 then use `WebClient` object to upload file to site 2. More details on how to use web-request to upload and download files can be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WebRequestNResponseMDB12012005232323PM/WebRequestNResponseMDB.aspx).